# skip authentication for CKeditor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, cancan

i am using [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) in my Rails app. it works pretty well, but i did not manage to get the photo upload/brows/send to server to work !

i am using cancan and am getting `CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed at /pictures`,
even after commenting out the `config.authorize_with :cancan` in config/initializers/ckeditor.rb

so i thought about uncommenting `config.authorize_with :cancan` and then using `skip_authorization_check`, but i don't know where to use it! am new to rails.

i pretty much tried everything i can !

any help/leads/tips please ?

Comment: how does your ability.rb look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb` of the gem gives you the idea how to solve the issue. (use `bundle open ckeditor` from the root directory of your app, then navigate to `app/controller/ckeditor/`)

So, create a `ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb` in your Rails app with the content:

```
class Ckeditor::PicturesController < Ckeditor::ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @picture = Ckeditor::Picture.new
    respond_with_asset(@picture)
  end 

  def destroy
    @picture.destroy
    respond_with(@picture, :location => pictures_path)
  end 

protected

  def authorize_resource
    model = (@picture || Ckeditor::Picture)
    @authorization_adapter.try(:authorize, params[:action], model)
  end 
end
```

The key to this solution is the `load_and_authorize_resource` and the `authorize_resource` and `create` method, you'll be able to upload pictures.

The `destroy` method gets called when you want to delete the uploaded images.